# Building openwrt on centos7

Tags: openwrt, centos7

I am trying to build openWRT on CentOS7(64bits) by using command like `make`, but its giving error like

> svn: /home/shwetha/openwrt/trunk/staging_dir/host/lib/liblzma.so.5: no version information available (required by /lib64/libselinux.so.1)

I tried changing some configurations but its giving same error:

```
 /home/shwetha/openwrt/trunk/staging_dir/host/lib/liblzma.so.5: no version information available (required by /lib64/libselinux.so.1)
 /lib64/libselinux.so.1: undefined reference to 'lzma_code@XZ_5.0'
 /lib64/libselinux.so.1: undefined reference to 'lzma_stream_decoder@XZ_5.0'
 /lib64/libselinux.so.1: undefined reference to 'lzma_end@XZ_5.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed about two week ago in OpenWrt trunk and CC, see this:
https://dev.openwrt.org/changeset/46603

You have to update to a more recent trunk or CC version, or manually update xz in the tools directory to version 5.2.1, for example by cherry-picking the commit I mentioned.